# understanding /dev/disk/by- folders

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, uuid

**Question**: What does `/dev/disk/by-path`describe? And where is this documented?

Going through the meaning of what is displayed in the folders `/dev/disk/by-` I've got that far, and I wonder **is this correct**?

- `by-id` → based upon the serial number of the hardware devices
- `by-label` → Whatever name was set manually for this disk
- `by-path` → **?!**
- `by-uuid` →  [Universal Unique Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid): a uniquely created string to identify the disk [done so through the system]

[Note: I work on GNU/Linux Debian 7, Crunchbang, if this matters…]

Comment: First result in google: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/persistent_naming.html

Comment: On my system (x86_64 Arch linux, installed within the last 3 months) all of the /dev/disk/by-*/ entries comprise symbolic links to /dev/sd[ab][1234567] block device files. Of what use are these various naming schemes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mountpoint `/dev` is `devtmpfs` filesystem and managed by `udev` completely.
So for details we have to go to `udev` configuration.

2 udev rules are handling this typically

```
$ grep -ri '/dev/disk' /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:# persistent storage links: /dev/disk/{by-id,by-uuid,by-label,by-path}
/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/13-dm-disk.rules:# These rules create symlinks in /dev/disk directory.
```

`60-persistent-storage.rules` mentions

```
# by-path (parent device path)
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", DEVPATH!="*/virtual/*", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}"
ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-part%n"
```

Finally `ID_PATH` is a unique identificator for a device based on it's physical HW location / connection (eg. something like ID_PATH=pci-0000:02:04.0-scsi-0:0:0:0).

`ID_PATH` comes from builtin udev program called `path_id` (eg. for `/sys/block/sdc`)

```
$ udevadm test-builtin path_id /sys/block/sdc
calling: test-builtin
=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          204
file size:         5632867 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1260755 bytes
nodes              4372032 bytes
load module index
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
```

We can relate it to

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 0 Aug 15 02:30 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/
```

Ultimately, if anybody is interested in details consult the source code

- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udev-builtin-path_id.c

Comment: so, e.g. `pci-0000:02:04.0-scsi-0:0:0:0` describes that the device is connected from PCI bus to SCSI adapter and thus describing hardware connections? Is this right?

Comment: Right. I've updated the answer above for some details where does the `ID_PATH` actually come from.

Answer (score 4):

`by-path`  is access disk way.
For Local disk, `by-path` is pci path of disk device.
For iSCSI disk, `by-path` is iSCSI path of remote disk device.

System can use `by-path` to location disk device!

Answer (score 3):

```
by-id    - creates a unique name depending on the hardware serial number.
by-label - almost every file system type can have a label.
           All your volumes that have one are listed in the /dev/disk/by-label directory.
by-path  - creates a unique name depending on the shortest physical path to the device
by-uuid  - is a mechanism to give each filesystem a unique identifier.
           These identifiers are generated by the mkfs utilities.
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer